# How do I shift the text to the right of the checkbox in CSS?

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm having a little trouble shift the text "I agree to everything that will happen after I submit this form. Take All my data!" to the right of the checkbox and have the checkbox in line with the other text on the left-hand side. The code is in the codepen link below, any input would be greatly appreciated!

[Sign in form below](https://codepen.io/Hollow27/pen/qKyOKZ/)

HTML Below:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
</head>
<form>
  <h1>Sign up for the newsletter</h1>

  <body>
    <br></br>
    <p>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input id="name" name="Name" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input id="email" name="Email" type="email">
    </p>

    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="true" />I agree to everything that will happen after I submit this form. Take All my data!</label>

    <br></br>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="submit">
    </p>
  </body>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
</script>

<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

</html>
```

CSS Below:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round');    
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500');


form {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 4em 4em 2em;
  max-width: 420px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em #222;
  border-radius: 9px;
  position: relative;
}


h1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-color: black;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}


body {
  font-size: 7px;
  background: #d7d7d7; /* fallback */
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  position: relative;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  color: #333;
}

input {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"] {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  padding: .8em .5em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus {
  background: #fff
}

input[type="submit"] {
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  background: #f45226;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 30%;
  border: none;
  color: #fefefe;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: auto;
  outline: none;
  padding: 8px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #f45226;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(165, 126, 157, 0.62);
}

input[type="submit"]:active {
  top: 1px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

label[type="checkbox"] {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

Comment: The first opening tag after `</head>` must be `<body>`

Answer (score 1):

**Issue**:

1. Your input has `display: block;` which takes the entire available width
2. Your input has `width: 100%`, you don't need this.

[image]

**Solution**:

Add a class to your checkbox, so that the new styles will apply only to this particular checkbox. `.terms-checkbox`

CSS

```
input.terms-checkbox {
  display:inline;
  width: auto;
}
```

Check here : https://codepen.io/kiranvj/pen/BVPKLN

Comment: I'm guessing this portion of the CSS is to match the width of the text inputs with the width of the container. But it is also applying to the checkbox (centering it), although the checkbox ignores the setting except that it centers.

Comment: @Wayne, yes, that might be the case here. For checkbox and radio even if we give `width: 100%` it will take the available space, but the appearance of checkbox will be of same size.

Comment: Less CSS is best CSS.

Comment: +1 for looking into the future and avoiding the "What was I thinking?" when the page needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

update your css as below :

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
margin-left: -20px;
display: inline-block;
width: auto;    
margin-right: 10px;
```

}

Updated code pen : https://codepen.io/bhupendra1011/pen/eKjJwW

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `width` and `display` property for your input element. Try this code.

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500');


form {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 4em 4em 2em;
  max-width: 420px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em #222;
  border-radius: 9px;
  position: relative;
}


h1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-color: black;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}


body {
  font-size: 7px;
  background: #d7d7d7; /* fallback */
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  position: relative;
}
label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  color: #333;
}
input {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"] {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  padding: .8em .5em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus {
  background: #fff
}

input[type="submit"] {
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  background: #f45226;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 30%;
  border: none;
  color: #fefefe;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: auto;
  outline: none;
  padding: 8px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #f45226;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(165, 126, 157, 0.62);
}

input[type="submit"]:active {
  top: 1px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.checkbox {
  padding-left: 20px;
  position:relative;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
</head>
    <form>
    <h1>Sign up for the newsletter</h1>
    <body>

    <br></br>
        <p>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" name="Name" type="text">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input id="email" name="Email" type="email">
  </p>

    <label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value="true" /> I agree to everything that will happen after I submit this form. Take All my data!</label>    

    <br></br>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="submit">
        </p>
      </body>
    </form>
    <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  </script>

    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your checkbox is inheriting the properties of your input CSS that are centering the other input elements.

```
input {
  display: block;
  **margin: auto;**
  box-sizing: border-box;
  **width: 100%;**
  outline: none
}
```

Reset those back to not center.

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-left: 0;
    width: auto;
}
```